# Mysql Pivot Table with where clause

Tags: mysql

```
select student_id, class_id, section_id, exam_date, exam_id, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-1)))) as sub1, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-2)))) as sub2, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-3)))) as sub3, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-4)))) as sub4, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-5)))) as sub5, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-6)))) as sub6 
from result 
where class_id = '7' and section id = '3' and YEAR(exam_date) = '2012' and exam_id = '3'
GROUP BY student_id
```

I have a problem that when I filter with where clause all number values get 0, if I run query without where clause the result will good but from all database.
How can I filter query with where clause?
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by class_id too

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
select student_id, class_id,  
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-1)))) as sub1,  
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-2)))) as sub2,  
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-3)))) as sub3,  
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-4)))) as sub4,  
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-5)))) as sub5,  
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-6)))) as sub6  
from result GROUP BY student_id,class_id) m 
where class_id = '7'
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the query before where.

```
SELECT * FROM (
select student_id, class_id, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-1)))) as sub1, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-2)))) as sub2, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-3)))) as sub3, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-4)))) as sub4, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-5)))) as sub5, 
       sum(number*(1-abs(sign(subject-6)))) as sub6 
from result GROUP BY student_id) m
where class_id = '7'
```